# Why following code doesnt override base class property in C++ CLI?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli, overriding

I'm a C# programmer and don't know much about C++.
Any idea why I'm getting error ?

```
ref class masterWeapon{
public :
    virtual property int Slot {
        int get(){
            return -1;
        }
    }
};

ref class Weapon1 : masterWeapon{

public :
    virtual property int Slot{
//following like throw an error :  cannot override base class method 
        int get() override = masterWeapon::Slot::get{
            return 1;
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: That's not valid C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza But maybe it's valid c++-cli *shudder* :p

Comment: It's C++0x CLI (Managed C++)

Comment: I edited the question title and removed the C++ tag to make clear that this is not about vanilla C++ but about a feature specific to Microsofts CLI extension of the C++ language.

Comment: @sixlettervariables I'm using Visual Studio 2012( Version 11 ) but I have no idea how to get my compiler version.

Comment: @Mahdi: There's no such thing. It's "C++/CLI".

Comment: I never thought this to be so hard to answer !

Comment: It is just plain int get() override { return 1; }, the = is invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the `= masterWeapon::Slot::get` portion and it will compile. If you read the error message that accompanies C3764 it makes this a bit more obvious (but not 100%):

> ...because the base method is explicitly overridden by `'Weapon1::Slot::get'`

Giving us the following code:

```
ref class Weapon1 : masterWeapon{
public :
    virtual property int Slot {
        int get() override {
            return 1;
        }
    }
};
```

Which when run against:

```
masterWeapon^ weapon1 = gcnew masterWeapon();
masterWeapon^ weapon2 = gcnew Weapon1();

Console::WriteLine(L"weapon1->Slot = {0}", weapon1->Slot);
Console::WriteLine(L"weapon2->Slot = {0}", weapon2->Slot);
```

Results in:

> weapon1->Slot = -1
>
> weapon2->Slot = 1

Comment: Actually I were working on this for more than one hour and couldn't figure it out!. thanks